# How do I handle exiting ScalaFX

Tags: scalafx

I use `java.util.Timer` to run a method every 10th of a second.

I have to cancel this before exiting ScalaFX.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JFXApp](http://www.scalafx.org/api/8.0/index.html#scalafx.application.JFXApp) has method `stopApp` that is called when the application stops. You can cancel your timer there.

Comment: It works! Overriding the JFXApp stopApp() was the answer. 

override def stopApp() {
    tempTimer.cancel()
    stage.close()
  }